# Change color text using Label

Tags: html, typescript, xhtml, nativescript

How to change text color on menu bar when using `Label` Nativescript.

My code:

```
        <StackLayout row="1" orientation="horizontal" backgroundColor="#eae8e8" class="foot">
            <Label width="25%" textAlignment="left" [nsRouterLink]="['/photos']">
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Photos"></Span>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
   <Label width="25%" textAlignment="left" [nsRouterLink]="['/albums']">
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Albums"></Span>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
         </StackLayout>
```

I want like this [image] When click

Comment: can you please add playground demo?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, demo: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=gMhuwo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `color` attribute both in CSS and direct HTML to specify the color to the element.
for example:

```
zontal" backgroundColor="#eae8e8" class="foot">
            <Label width="25%" textAlignment="left" [nsRouterLink]="['/photos']">
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span color="blue" text="Photos"></Span>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
   <Label width="25%" textAlignment="left" [nsRouterLink]="['/albums']">
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Albums"></Span>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
         </StackLayout>
```

here is playground demo:https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=gMhuwo&v=2

Comment: Can you change and image please?

Comment: i didn't get it. can you explain more?

Comment: @bhavinjalodara can u help me on this??   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262183/assertion-failure-and-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-nativescript

Comment: can't help. i don't have experience with xCode